# convert greyscale image back to vector

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, grayscale

I have a list called `w` (size: 784), which I outputted to a png greyscale image:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
tmp = 1/(1+np.exp(-10*w/w.max()))
plt.imshow(tmp.reshape(28,28),cmap="gray")
plt.draw()
plt.savefig("final_weight_vector")
```

Now I want to read the png image *back* to be a vector.

The solutions I found so far:

First:

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
img=mpimg.imread('final_weight_vector.png')
```

but `img` appears to not be greyscale, because its dimensions turend out to be (600, 800, 4).

Second:

reading the file as RGB and converting to greyscale:

```
im = Image.open('final_weight_vector.png').convert('LA')
```

However, I couldn't find how to iterate over `im` so I have no idea as to what's inside. Further, I am not sure the output of `im` will have the exact same values as the original `w`.

Help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that what you saved is probably a plot of the 28x28 image, not the image itself.

To be sure, please preview the image. I bet it is 600x800, not 28x28. I also suppose it contains many additional elements, like axes and padding.

If you want to store your array in a loadable format, you may use `numpy.save()` (and `numpy.load()` to load it).

You may also use PIL to save your array as image (e.g. using something similar to: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577591-conversion-of-pil-image-and-numpy-array/)

Comment: Lot's of betting and supposing. Better to ask OP to edit and clarify the original question.